# .htaccess block php in /users folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I need to block php execution in all subdirectory of /users using .htaccess... 
I'm using this but it don't work.

```
 <Directory users/*>
     <FilesMatch "(?i)\.(php|php3?|phtml)$">
            Order Deny,Allow
            Deny from All
    </FilesMatch>
 </Directory>
```

Comment: `<Directory>` doesn't work in `.htaccess` so it is not `.htaccess` question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use full path to user in your code, like this:

```
 <Directory **fullPathTo**/USERS>
```

Or you can also do a location match:

```
<LocationMatch "/USERS/.*(?i)\.(php3?|phtml)$">
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
</LocationMatch>
```